# Change DataTemplate textblock Visibility determined by parent container type

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have a `<DataTemplate>` as defined below, which contains a `<TextBlock>`

The `<DataTemplate>` is used in several instances of a `<ListBox>` and reused elsewhere in a `<ContentControl>`

*Note code simplified for brevity*

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="SetsItemTemplate" DataType="viewModel:SetVm">
   <TextBlock 
       Visibility="{Binding <somethign here i guess>, 
          ConverterParameter=collapse, 
          Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisConverter}}">
   </TextBlock>
</DataTemplate>

<ListBox ItemTemplate="{StaticResource SetsItemTemplate}" />

<ContentControl ContentTemplate="{StaticResource SetsItemTemplate}" />
```

The `<TextBlock>` has a boolToVisibility Converter to collapse the `<TextBlock>` on a condition, however i really need that condition to check if the parent container is a `<ContentControl>`

I.e If the `<DataTemplate>` parent is a `<ContentControl>` collapse the `<TextBlock>`

Maybe i could use Names to make this easier (i'm not sure)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to access the parent, you need to get the `sender` or the source object. There is no way you can get this using `IValueConverter`. But, they already have a solution for this:

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/9f3e4f6d-20d2-4c13-90a2-7c157ed4f8c3/ivalueconverter-pass-calling-object-as-converterparameter?forum=wpf

Now, you can access the element and get the parent through:

```
element = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(element) as UIElement;
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

You can change the visibility based on the parent element as mentioned in the above msdn link. you can achieve this by using parent element name property with BoolToVisibilityConverter. Like bind the element name to TextBlock Visibility property with converter and define the visibility in converter based on the bounded ElementNameProperty.